# Portable Code C++ in windows and Linux

Tags: c++, portability

I would like to written application in C++ that must be compatible with both linux and windows. The requirement is that I need to develop in Linux G++ compiler and run it in Windows platform too.
I would appreciate if you can provide me direction regarding how to start development? Which IDE to use and which libraries I need to use to make code compatible. In addition, I want to develop UI as well in the same application so which type of project I should create (Like Web Project in Java I do) Thanks.

Comment: Use CodeBlocks or DevCpp on Windows, these also use G++

Comment: Everyone seems to be ponying up ideas for IDE's, but your question seems to suggest you're interested in the difficulty in writing portable *code* across Windows and Linux (gui? console? both?). Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, I already download CodeBlock but now I am afraid how to start development. I also search Boost library so should I download this one?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to use [Qt](http://qt-project.org/). It is cross-platform, has good IDE (Qt Creator), and allows to create GUI.

Answer (score 2):

The best IDE is the Unix development environment itself: you don't
really want all the GUI stuff which restricts your options.  If you're
just starting, it's nice to avoid having to deal with makefiles, etc.,
but if you're worried about portability, you're going to have to deal
with them anyway.

For the rest, portability depends on what your application has to do.
You can do a lot using standard C++, which is sort of portable.  You'll
still have to deal with the fact that different compilers implement
different versions of the standard, more or less well, but if you stick
to C++03, you shouldn't have too many problems.

There are a lot of things that standard C++ doesn't cover, however.  The
socket interface (for networking) is fairly similar between the two
systems, and it shouldn't be too hard to wrap it in a C++ class which
hides the differencees.  Things like reading directories or threading
can be done using Boost, which hides the differences.  If you need
transactional integrity, you'll need to wrap the file accesses, since
the names of the functions and there arguments are very different
between the two systems.  (I'm not even sure that transactional
integrity is possible under Windows.)  The GUI interface is
totally different; your best bet would be to use a portable GUI
interface like wxWidgets.

Finally, no matter how many precautions you take, expect some things not to work immediately when you port.  (Or as it was once expressed: "The only  portable code is code which has been ported.")

Answer (score 1):

eclipse or QtCreator may be your choice
you can also use MINGW and configure the environment and use emacs to do your task